# hiding one gridview should auto resize adjacent gridview

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have two asp.net gridviews side by side and one of them will be hidden dynamically. When that happens i want the other to stretch/auto resize to occupy empty space.

```
<div class="col-md-9"style="border:1px solid black;">
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="myGridClass" runat="server"  HorizontalAlign="Center" >
     </asp:GridView> 

     <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" CssClass="myGridClass" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server">
     </asp:GridView> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Kindly share what css you have used in `myGridClass`.

Comment: .myGridClass {
    display:inline-flex;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border: solid 1px #525252;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: Visible;
}

Comment: How are you planning to hide this gridview?

Comment: Gridview2.Visible = false; in the code behind

Comment: Dropped you a solution. Just have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a workaround to achieve this. Create a similar CSS class in your `stylesheet` and change it's width from `auto` to `100%`. Now, in your code behind just after `Gridview2.Visible = false;` add a new line that will assign a new CSS class to gridview.

**CSS Class File**

---

```
.myGridClassStretch {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border: solid 1px #525252;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: Visible;
}
```

**Code Behind**

---

```
Gridview2.Visible = false;
Gridview1.CSSClass = "myGridClassStretch";
```

Comment: If you want to auto-size your column to fit the space then remove `display` property from css class.

Comment: Thanks!! This works perfectly.But I was looking for a solution from CSS. I had to modify a lot in my code behind to make this work.

Comment: Welcome. If my answer has solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept this as an answer. This would help us (contributors) to build reputation in this community.